# Android: Tab Indicator line disappears when tab background is changed

Tags: android, android-tabs, fragment-tab-host

My question is more or less similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30796003/5366183) question, but the response approved as the answer for the same doesn't solve my issue.

I'm implementing tab structures using the `FragmentTabHost` class. When the tab background color is not  explicitly specified, the tab indicator line seems to appear as `Android` provides. But when I programatically change the tab's background color, the tab indicators disappear (hidden).

Currently, I assign the tab background color this way :

```
 private void customizeTabbs() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mTabHost.getTabWidget().getTabCount(); i++) {
        View tabChild= mTabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i);
        ..
        ..
        tabChild.setBackgroundResource(someColorResource);

    }

}
```

I also tried to change the background color in the `XML` way by adding to `styles.xml` , following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30904139/5366183) as:

```
 <item name="tabBackground">@color/someColor</item>
 <item name="tabIndicatorColor">?@color/someOtherColor</item>
```

The solution suggested for one similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9726190/5366183) also did not help me.

Comment: Are you changing all the tab colors or only the current selected tab?

Comment: @Srijith I'm programatically setting the background color for the tabs and I don't want it to change during select/deselect and that's the code I've mentioned.